# Syntax error on nested else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I can't figure out why I am getting a syntax error on else, figured you guys could help.
The program is fairly simple it's just meant to find the largest number out of 10 numbers.

```
package Largest;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LargestTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


int number;
int numberCounter = 0;
int largest = 0 ;

while (numberCounter <= 10 ){
    out.println("Please enter in a number");
    number = input.nextInt();
    if (number > largest){
        number = largest;
        numberCounter++;
    else {
        numberCounter++;    }
    }
}



}


}
```

Comment: You need another `}` somewhere there (after the `if`)

Comment: Use **auto-formating** of your IDE. Also braces are often paired when position at one brace, or there is collapse/expand outline in the left margin for blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you forget `}` of the `if` like this

```
if (number > largest) {
        number = largest;
        numberCounter++;

}  // <----- you forget this
else {
        numberCounter++;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a closing bracket for your if statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (number > largest){
    number = largest;
    numberCounter++;
else {
    numberCounter++;    }
```

should be

```
if (number > largest){
    number = largest;
    numberCounter++;
**}**else {
    numberCounter++;    
}
```

and then you should remove one of the `}` that you have at the end of your class.

Comment: I am sorry, I was too slow and I didn't see the other answers. I anyway consider relevant taking into account that it is not that this person missed the `}`, but that it was in the wrong place (at the end of the class or after the else).

Comment: No worries in that case, I see what you mean :) +1